# Using 'or' condition in an XSL transformation

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to do an XSL transformation to obtain some values from XML that looks like this:

```
<FOO_CODE>ACPRE</FOO_CODE>
<FOO_SCORE>100</FOO_SCORE>
```

However, it's possible that the FOO_CODE will be different for each different XML file, so I would like to use an 'or' statement in the XSL transformation. My XSL looks like this:

```
 <xsl:for-each select="FOO_CODE">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test=". ='ACPRE or FEPRE or ECGRE'">
                         <NEW_FOO_CODE>ACPRE</NEW_FOO_CODE>
                         <NEW_FOO_SCORE>100</NEW_FOO_SCORE>
                       </xsl:when>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:for-each>
```

The 'or' condition does not appear to be working though as when it's run, the transformation does not populate any data into the new nodes. When I remove the 'or' condition and just test for the value in the specific XML file, it does work.

Can anyone advise on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
  <xsl:for-each select="FOO_CODE">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="(.='ACPRE') or (.='FEPRE') or (.='ECGRE')">
        <NEW_FOO_CODE>ACPRE</NEW_FOO_CODE>
        <NEW_FOO_SCORE>100</NEW_FOO_SCORE>
      </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:for-each>
```

You can not provide the values to compare inside single quote. It would be considered as normal value instead of operator. It will not be treated as operator but value.